# installing RDFLIB package in python 3.4

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to install `rdflib` package in Python. I have anaconda 3.4 installed on my system, I tried installing this package in `spyder` with the following command:

```
!pip install python-rdflib
```

but it is not installing. please help to install rdflib package.

Comment: What does the "!pip" stand for? is is a typo?

Comment: Did you got an error message after you run your command, if yes, which one?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE i tried it in python console so i used '!'..

Comment: @BastianW error is error 13 IO error, permission denied

Comment: @BastianW: We can make the assumption that Girish Khole tried a system-wide installation. He didn't has access right to modify its system installation. This is why I recommend him to use a virtualenv instead (which is the best way).

Comment: @Laurent yes i thought the same, but i thought I better ask before I trow in my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install everithing in a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/) and not system-wide:

```
virtualenv myapp
source myapp/bin/activate
pip install anaconda  # or something similar (see below).
pip install rdflib
```

For more information:

- http://www.simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial-part-2/
- https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Comment: following error occurred after running

pip install python-rdflib

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-rdflib (from ve
rsions: )
No matching distribution found for python-rdflib

Comment: Wrong library name! Try: `pip install rdflib`. And read the [documentation](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/).

Answer (score 0):

pip install rdflib

run this command in command prompt (Command prompt should be run as administrator) and wait till installing the package.. after installing package in command prompt open spyder or any python IDE and call
import rdflib.. it worked for me...